# Terraform: Failed to query available Provider package on M1 Pro

Tags: terraform, devops

I am using the new apple M1 pro and when I run terraform init I am getting failed to query available Provider package error

The error

```
Reusing previous version of newrelic/newrelic from the dependency lock file
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws: locked provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws 2.70.0 does not match configured version constraint ~>
│ 3.53.0; must use terraform init -upgrade to allow selection of new versions
╵

╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider ns1-terraform/ns1: could not connect to registry.terraform.io: Failed to request discovery document: Get
│ "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
╵

╷
│ Error: Incompatible provider version
│ 
│ Provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0 does not have a package available for your current platform, darwin_arm64.
│ 
│ Provider releases are separate from Terraform CLI releases, so not all providers are available for all platforms. Other versions of this provider may have different platforms supported.
╵

╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│ 
│ Error while installing newrelic/newrelic v2.25.0: could not query provider registry for registry.terraform.io/newrelic/newrelic: failed to retrieve authentication checksums for provider: the
│ request failed after 2 attempts, please try again later: Get
│ "https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/93446098/7aca5d90-9fc0-43cd-946b-46f556c2bbfa?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20211215%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211215T180026Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=01f9b195e6e9355253a588d09c73a78f499e6d1b1f2014f921e749b0da9c4c4e&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=93446098&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dterraform-provider-newrelic_2.25.0_SHA256SUMS&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream":
│ net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Answer (score 4):

This set of errors seems to be describing three separate problems at once:

- Your Terraform configuration declares that it needs a version of the `hashicorp/aws` provider which matches the version constraint `~> 3.53.0`, which is the same as `>= 3.53.0, < 3.34.0`, that doesn't match the version `2.70.0` that was selected on a previous Terraform run.

  If you have intentionally changed the version constraint in order to upgrade the provider, you can follow the advice in that particular error and run `terraform init -upgrade` to select the newest version of each provider which matches the version constraints. Alternatively, you can revert the change to the version constraints so that the configuration will accept `2.70.0` as a suitable version and then keep using that version.
- Your configuration depends on the legacy provider `hashicorp/template`, which unfortunately reached end-of-life before Apple introduced Apple Silicon-based products, and so that particular provider does not have any packages available which can run on your M1 Mac.

  You may be able to work around this by running the `darwin_amd64` build of Terraform CLI under Rosetta 2 emulation, which will then in turn cause Terraform to install and run the `darwin_amd64` versions of the providers also in Rosetta 2 emulation.

  For modern Terraform you should typically use [the `templatefile` function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile) instead of [the deprecated `template_file` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file), as recommended in the documentation, but I would suggest making sure that you're able to work with your *current* configuration using Rosetta 2 emulation first, before modifying it to remove the deprecated provider, because that will allow you to compare the behavior before and after the change and thus make sure you've not inadvertently changed configuration behavior.

  However, once you've moved away from using the deprecated provider, you should be able to use the native Apple Silicon build of Terraform (the `darwin_arm64` version you are already using) for future work on this configuration, because this provider is the only one generating that particular error message here.
- Finally, Terraform seems to have encountered some network connectivity problems when attempting automatic provider installation. It seems that this isn't a *total* failure to reach the Terraform Registry and the provider packages hosted on GitHub, because Terraform was clearly able to query `registry.terraform.io` in order to learn what versions of `hashicorp/template` are available, but *some* requests are not succeeding and so perhaps you are accessing the internet through a corporate firewall or similar filtering which is making a subset of the requests fail, for some reason.

Since this has ended up being at least three questions at once, if you have any further questions about any one of these answers then I'd suggest starting a new Stack Overflow question about it, including any additoinal context as necessary, because that will hopefully then allow folks who want to answer to have more context and thus give you a more actionable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a Macbook with an M1 chip as well I kept facing the same error. To fix, I had to uninstall terraform "brew uninstall terraform", follow these instructions https://benobi.one/posts/running_brew_on_m1_for_x86/, run "ibrew install hashicorp/tap/terraform".

Although "terraform version" will provide the same output as before, it now works. For me at least. Hope this helps someone!